# Return Only SQLite Join Statements

Tags: python, database, sqlite, left-join, statements

I am working with SQLite on a regular basis and I want to know what the join statements are for a given database. I know how to read them out of the database by just running:

SELECT * from sqlite_master;

(often running a WHERE statement for "REFERENCES" or "JOIN")

But this obviously returns the entire create statement for the table. I only want to return the JOIN statement itself (and save it to a text file). I have been working with Python Regular Expressions and can get maybe 75 percent of all databases, while the last 25% are "close" but not exact as the developers used different statement structure. I have about 5 different RE that the database can run through, but it is getting to the point where I have to write an RE for each databases... which kind of defeats the point hah.

PRAGMA foreign_key_list only works on databases that use the REFERENCES keyword... or if there is a PRAGMA I am not aware of I would be open to use it.

Is there anyway with SQLite and/or Python to carve out JUST the Join statements consistently across databases?

Comment: What do you mean by this? `JOIN` is part of a query that you write to select information from a database, it's not part of the schema of a database.

Comment: When the database creates a table it uses create statements, and it sets up the join statements to connect the tables. These are stored in sqlite_master.

Comment: Edited for clarity...

Comment: Please edit for correctness. I guess you mean something related to foreign key constraints.

Comment: Figured it out on my own.